# Remove words from the string which are present in list

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using the following python program to remove stopwords from the texts.

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text

mylist= [['an_undergraduate'], ['state_of_the_art', 'terminology']]
######Remove stops
stops = list(text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS)
pattern = re.compile(r'|'.join([r'(\_|\b){}\b'.format(x) for x in stops]))
for k in mylist:
    for idx, item in enumerate(k):
        if item not in stops:
            item = pattern.sub('', item).strip()
            k[idx] = item
```

I want the output as

```
mylist= [['undergraduate'], ['state_art', 'terminology']]
```

However, the pattern I have mentioned does not capture the stop words properly. Please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Just to be clear, once you remove the stopwords, you also do not want extra `_` characters correct?

Comment: @chrisz yes, can we also do that using regex? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the sourcecode of [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/stop_words.py#L4), it is of type [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html). Hence, no need to type-cast it to `list`. Instead of using `regex`, using this nested *list comprehension* expression will be much more performance efficient.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
>>> mylist= [['an_undergraduate'], ['state_of_the_art', 'terminology']]

>>> [['_'.join([w for w in i.split('_') if w not in text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS]) for i in e] for e in mylist]
[['undergraduate'], ['state_art', 'terminology']]
```

Here I am firstly splitting the words based on underscore, checking whether the word is present in the `ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS`, and filtering the words for new string only if it is not present.